# What do the size settings for MemoryCache mean?

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-core-2.1, memorycache

In a controller class, I have

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
private IMemoryCache _cache;
private readonly MemoryCacheEntryOptions CacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
    .SetSize(1)
    // Keep in cache for this time
    .SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(CacheExpiryInSeconds));
```

And in Startup.cs, I have

```
public class MyMemoryCache
    {
        public MemoryCache Cache { get; set; }
        public MyMemoryCache()
        {
            Cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions
            {
                SizeLimit = 1024,
            });
        }
    }
```

What do these various size settings mean?

This is .NET Core 2.1.

Comment: The documentation is shockingly terrible on `Size`.  It seems reasonable to expect it to be bytes since it is an `Int64` type.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I was able to hunt down some helpful [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-setsize-size-and-sizelimit-to-limit-cache-size).

> SizeLimit does not have units. Cached entries must specify size in whatever units they deem most appropriate if the cache size limit has been set. All users of a cache instance should use the same unit system. An entry will not be cached if the sum of the cached entry sizes exceeds the value specified by SizeLimit. If no cache size limit is set, the cache size set on the entry will be ignored.

It turns out that SizeLimit can function as the limit on the number of entries, not the size of those entries.

A quick sample app showed that with a SizeLimit of 1, the following:

```
var options = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetSize(1);
cache.Set("test1", "12345", options);
cache.Set("test2", "12345", options);

var test1 = (string)cache.Get("test1");
var test2 = (string)cache.Get("test2");
```

`test2` will be null.

In turn, `SetSize()` allows you to control exactly how much of your size limit an entry should take.  For instance, in the following example:

```
var cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions
{
    SizeLimit = 3,
});

var options1 = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetSize(1);
var options2 = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetSize(2);
cache.Set("test1", "12345", options1);
cache.Set("test2", "12345", options2);

var test1 = (string)cache.Get("test1");
var test2 = (string)cache.Get("test2");
```

both `test1` and `test2` will have been stored in the cache.  But if `SizeLimit` is set to `2`, only the first entry will be successfully stored.

Comment: So `SetSize` defines how many units each entry take up, and `SizeLimit` is the max amount of these units that the cache may contain?

Comment: @ThorkilVærge Exactly.  `SetSize` gives you fine-grain control over the sizing of each unit . This would allow you have multiple `MemoryCacheEntryOptions`, each with their own sizing.  I updated my answer with an additional example.

Comment: In the second snippet, what does it mean for `test2` to be of size `2`? More generally, what are the use-cases to specify a size larger than 1 for some cache entry?

Comment: @OfirD, size is an entirely arbitrary measurement that you as the developer would assign to your entries.  For most use cases, you would always treat every cached object as an equal size as others and in reality, that may often be the case.  However, consider an instance where you cache payloads returned from an API you do not control, and the payloads might be highly variable.  In that scenario, you might want to check character length/byte array size prior to caching and apply a sliding size based on breakpoints.  Alternatively, you could use size as priority and only cache if there is room.

Comment: Also note for those using MemoryCache indirectly through IDistributedCache. The documentation was unclear what units the SizeLimit was in since there was no equivalent cache entry option on the generic distributed cache options: `DistributedCacheEntryOptions`.  Since the interface uses byte[] I assumed the units was number of bytes but found no documentation indicating this.  Found this in the source code which proved my assumption: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/src/MemoryDistributedCache.cs#L77

Comment: Why on earth would I want test2 to be null if it can’t ’fit’ in the cache? Surely I would want an exception or for the oldest item to be purged? Every time I look at IMemoryCache I understand it less!

Comment: @Simon_Weaver that's a consequence of using the Get method directly. When using a non-try variant, you only have two options to indicate a lack of success. Either you can throw (not optimal here) or you can return null/default. It isn't great, but I'd argue that null is better than an exception. Keep in mind that you can also use the `TryGetValue` method instead to avoid having to determine if null is a cache miss or not.

Comment: @DavidL so `cache.Set("test2"...)` just does nothing without exception? I'm not able to test it right now but that's doesn't sound right. Whether using `Get` or `TryGet` wouldn't have anything to do with it if the Set is what's failing.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver it might not sound right, but to my understanding, it is. You can check the source for SetEntries here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/src/MemoryCache.cs#L142. If the capacity is exceeded, it doesn't set the entry nor does it throw. There's no benefit to setting an entry in the cache if the size is exceeded, since then the cache would have to track that entry that is-set-but-cannot-be-returned.

Comment: @DavidL I see at least in that case it sets the entry as 'Expired' and triggers compaction. I suppose the moral of the story is don't `Set` an entry and expect to `Get` it right away! In normal usage you wouldn't ever do that. I suppose since a cache is meant to be a somewhat transient thing then there wouldn't be any guarantee that `set` would actually add the item. But there MUST be many people using `IMemoryCache` for whom this is happening and they have no clue. I've left my size unconstrained and I have plenty of memory for what I need, but it's good to know for the future :-)

Comment: @Simon_Weaver it sets the entry to expired, yes, but it doesn't add it to the internal state of the cache. As a result, if you are holding onto the entry, it'll show that expired status but you won't be able to re-retrieve it from the cache. And I would fully agree with you that you may not be able to expect the cache to be updated. As a result, double-checked locking is always recommended if you have a sensitive upstream resource that is priming your cache.

Answer (score 1):

`SizeLimit` means what is the total volume?
`Size` or what the `SetSize` do is to specify what share of the total volume does it require?

For example in following code:

```
var cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions
{
    SizeLimit = 3,
});
```

It is said that the total volume is equal to 3. Based on this total volume, in the following code:

```
1>> cache.Set("item1", "I am ITEM 1", new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetSize(2));
2>> cache.Set("item2", "I am ITEM 2", new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetSize(2));
3>> cache.Set("item3", "I am ITEM 3", new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetSize(1));
```

In line 1, we need to store something in cache which it requires 2 of the total available volume of 3. Since the requested volume is available, then the operation is performed. The total available volume now is: `3-2=1`

In line 2, again we need to store something in cache which it needs 2 of the total available volume of 1. Since the requested volume is **not available**, the operation is **not performed**

In line 3, we need to store something in cache which it needs 1 of the total available volume of 1. Since the requested volume is available, then the operation is performed. The total available volume now is: `1-1=0`

Nothing will be cached from here on until some of the total volume is freed again.

So, in the following code:

```
var cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions
{
    SizeLimit = 3,
});

cache.Set("item1", "I am ITEM 1", new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetSize(2));
cache.Set("item2", "I am ITEM 2", new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetSize(2));
cache.Set("item3", "I am ITEM 3", new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetSize(1));

var item1 = (string)cache.Get("item1");
var item2 = (string)cache.Get("item2"); //<<! attention
var item3 = (string)cache.Get("item3");
```

`item1` and `item3` will contains the cached values, but `item2` will be null;